# Pandas Dataframe to Excel Sheet

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file (.xls format) with 5 sheets, I want to replace the contents of sheet 5 with contents of my pandas data frame.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

From your above needs, you will need to use both Python (to export pandas data frame) and VBA (to delete existing worksheet content and copy/paste external data).

With Python: use the [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) or [to_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) methods. I recommend the to_csv method which performs better with larger datasets.

```
# DF TO EXCEL
from pandas import ExcelWriter

writer = ExcelWriter('PythonExport.xlsx')
yourdf.to_excel(writer,'Sheet5')
writer.save()

# DF TO CSV
yourdf.to_csv('PythonExport.csv', sep=',')
```

With VBA: [copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx) and [paste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) source to destination ranges.

Fortunately, in VBA you can call Python scripts using Shell (assuming your OS is Windows).

```
Sub DataFrameImport()
  'RUN PYTHON TO EXPORT DATA FRAME
  Shell "C:\pathTo\python.exe fullpathOfPythonScript.py", vbNormalFocus

  'CLEAR EXISTING CONTENT
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Cells.Clear

  'COPY AND PASTE TO WORKBOOK
  Workbooks("PythonExport").Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Range("A1").Select
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(5).Paste
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can do vice versa: run a macro (ClearExistingContent) with Python. Be sure your Excel file is a macro-enabled (.xlsm) one with a saved macro to delete Sheet 5 content only. Note: macros cannot be saved with csv files.

```
import os
import win32com.client
from pandas import ExcelWriter

if os.path.exists("C:\Full Location\To\excelsheet.xlsm"):
  xlApp=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
  wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename="C:\Full Location\To\excelsheet.xlsm")

  # MACRO TO CLEAR SHEET 5 CONTENT
  xlApp.Run("ClearExistingContent")
  wb.Save() 
  xlApp.Quit()
  del xl

  # WRITE IN DATA FRAME TO SHEET 5
  writer = ExcelWriter('C:\Full Location\To\excelsheet.xlsm')
  yourdf.to_excel(writer,'Sheet5')
  writer.save()
```

Comment: Wanted something that python can do alone without using VBA but couldn't get it.. This worked fine though :) .

Comment: Hey @Parfait I used this code (modified for my own needs) Thank you :) but I get this error: 
`writer = ExcelWriter('Corner_Export.xlsx')
df_Entry.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
df_Apex.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet2')
df_Exit.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet3')
writer.save()`

`ImportError: No module named openpyxl`

Comment: StackOverflow, the gift that keep on giving! :) It seems your error may not relate to listed code. You are importing an uninstalled or wrongly declared module. This solution does not use `openpyxl`.

Comment: OParker, old error but it's because xlsxWriter is not installed, pandas fall back to openpyxl by default which seems not to exist either. a 'pip install' should solve your problem

Answer (score 5):

Or you can do like this:

```
your_df.to_excel( r'C:\Users\full_path\excel_name.xlsx',
                  sheet_name= 'your_sheet_name'
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the previous answers found here: Assuming that we want the other four sheets to remain, the previous answers here did not work, because the other four sheets were deleted. In case we want them to remain use xlwings:

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

filename = "test.xlsx"

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ("a", 1, 8, 3),
    ("b", 1, 2, 5),
    ("c", 3, 4, 6),
    ], columns=['one', 'two', 'three', "four"])

app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = xw.Book(filename)
ws = wb.sheets["Sheet5"]

ws.clear()
ws["A1"].options(pd.DataFrame, header=1, index=False, expand='table').value = df

# If formatting of column names and index is needed as xlsxwriter does it, 
# the following lines will do it (if the dataframe is not multiindex).
ws["A1"].expand("right").api.Font.Bold = True
ws["A1"].expand("down").api.Font.Bold = True
ws["A1"].expand("right").api.Borders.Weight = 2
ws["A1"].expand("down").api.Borders.Weight = 2

wb.save(filename)
app.quit()
```