# Using pandas how can we make different groups of the text(Coming from PDF output) and give them certain group ID?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have used some logic to iterate my tsv file in such a way that every text group will be given a group number. This code you can find in the answers, i have changed the question which i had earlier, with the help of @Jeril I was able to get this code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

main_df = pd.read_csv('sampleOutput.tsv', delimiter='\t')
main_df = main_df.dropna(subset=['text'], axis=0)

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for page_no in main_df['page_num'].unique():
    df = main_df[main_df['page_num'] == page_no].copy(deep=True)
    df['top'] = df['top'].astype(int)
    df['bool'] = (df['top'] - df['top'].shift(-1)) < -50
    df.loc[df['bool'] == True, 'group'] = range(
        1, (df['bool'] == True).sum() + 1)
    df['group'] = df['group'].replace({0: np.nan}).bfill()
    df['group'] = df['group'].fillna((df['bool'] == True).sum() + 1)
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df])

print(final_df)
```

So this is my table of which i have to get output of, the logic i have used is assuming threshold as (300,50), every text group will have a different groupNo, this i am doing so that i can display my output in a more sensible way.
Sentence grouping:
a) Words on same line are grouped if x distance < threshold
b) Words on next line are grouped with previous if y distance < threshold

x = current_left - previous_left (left refers to the "left" column)

y = current_line_top - previous_line_top (top refers to the "top" column)

INPUT:-
[image]

EXPECTED OUTPUT:- 
This is an example as to write the whole input again is difficult, basically every logical sentence will be in the same group, the logic is constant

**x = current line on 'left' column - previous line on 'left' column (left refers to the "left" column)**

x < Threshold(300)

**y = current_line_top_column - previous_line_top_column (top refers to the "top" column)**

y < Threshold(50)

I am not able to implement this logic, if anyone can help!

```
   page_num block_num   line_num    word_num    left    top width   text    groupNo
       1    27              1          1         405    420 129 Property    1
       1    27              1          2         543    420 31  of          1
       1    27              1          3         578    420 159 Accenture   1
       1    27              4          1         409    581 105 INTERPRET   2
       1    27              4          2         520    581 90  DRAWING     2
       1    27              4          3         616    581 38  PER         2
       1    27              4          4         659    581 113 APPLICABLE  2
       1    27              4          5         779    581 267 STANDARD:   2
       1    27              5          1         411    603 114 Accenture   2
       1    27              5          2         532    603 84  ACCOO1      2
       2    46              1          1         480    800 114 yoyoyo      3
       2    46              1          2         550    800 84  heloo      3
```

Please ask if the question is not clear.

Comment: What is groupNo, can you show an actual expectation of the groupNo column

Comment: @jeril is it more clear now ?

Comment: for the row where the text is `APPLICABLE` is the top column value 113 or 581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
main_df = pd.read_csv('codebeautify.tsv', delimiter='\t')
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for page_no in main_df['page_num'].unique():
    df = main_df[main_df['page_num'] == page_no].copy(deep=True)
    df['top'] = df['top'].astype(int)
    df['bool'] = ((df['top'] - df['top'].shift(-1)).abs() >
                  50) != ((df['left'] - df['left'].shift(-1)).abs() > 350)
    df.loc[df['bool'] == True, 'group'] = range(
        1, (df['bool'] == True).sum() + 1)
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df])
final_df['group'] = final_df['group'].replace({0: np.nan}).bfill()
final_df['group'] = final_df['group'].fillna((final_df['bool'] == True).sum() + 1)
```

Sample Output:

```
    left  top        text   bool  group
0    405  420    Property  False    1.0
1    543  420          of  False    1.0
2    578  420   Accenture   True    1.0
3    409  581   INTERPRET  False    2.0
4    520  581     DRAWING  False    2.0
5    616  581         PER  False    2.0
6    659  581  APPLICABLE  False    2.0
7    779  581    STANDARD   True    2.0
8    411  603   Accenture  False    3.0
9    532  603      ACCOO1   True    3.0
10   480  800      yoyoyo  False    4.0
11   550  800       heloo  False    4.0
```

Comment: is there anyway in which i dont have to write the whole column(top) manually, i wanted this generic as my table is having more than 1000 rows .???

Comment: you can just your same 'top' column, ignore how I am creating the dataframe.

Comment: can you tell me what to write i am not able to get it in this line

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [420, 420, 420, 581, 581, 581, 581, 581, 603, 603, 800, 800]
]).T.rename(columns={0: 'top'})

Thanks!

Comment: okay try `df = df[['top']]`, where `df` is the dataframe that you are creating from the `csv` file.

Comment: just one more help i was trying to get my outut directly in tsv or excel format, can you tell how to do that ?
thanks!

Comment: `df.to_csv("test.tsv", sep="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)` , refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29461151/2825570) for excel

Comment: I just checked, its still not working when the page number is changing the group number is not getting changed but it should change, i tried this on my big excel data but it wasnt working.  Like before with my code when the page number was changing the group number was changing as per the requirement.! 
PLEASE HELP

Comment: can you share the excel file

Comment: i have added please check .!@Jeril

Comment: Can you check now

Comment: it's still not working i read the code and i can see that you have written logic for the threshold for 'y'(i.e. if threshold is less 50 the condition will satisfy) but you haven't used to condition for 'x'(i.e. threshold less than 300) May be then it will work. 
The issue is its taking the whole line of the pdf as in one group but the main point because of which i assumed the threshold was for grouping the sentences which make sense.
Thanks just try once maybe youll get it, ask me if something is not clear !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188002/discussion-between-raghavender-rohilla-and-jeril).

Comment: example as in ? The logic is same just the threshold is getting changed in x direction. There is nothing different abt it, its just i am not able to make my code fast..

Comment: Consider the text `Accenture` in the group `Property of Accenture`, has the `left` column value as 50. Then in which group should it belong to?

Comment: Then "Accenture" will be in other group and "Property of" will be in other group, 
I am sure you must be also thinking how threshold is constant ? but it is not,
that will be next to task to figure out how to keep the threshold generic. May be this logic is also wrong for grouping, i am just experimenting things. If you have any other approach do let me know, it will be a help! 

Challenge was for y direction and it is still there, its just its better to break down the problem in parts. For now i am just targeting that these both logic work out.

Comment: So the line `1    27              4          5         779    581 267 STANDARD:   2` and `1    27              5          1         411    603 114 Accenture   2` must be two different groups right

Comment: No, they should be in the same group that is why we are on first place considering the y direction, because the sentence is together but on PDF file its on different lines, see considering both x and y is important at least with the help of that i can group them.

Comment: But you mentioned in the earlier comment when I asked about `Property of Accenture` you mentioned that they must be in different group, otherwise can you show how the output should look like, considering both x and y

Comment: No brother i will tell you the group's "Property of accenture"; "INTERPRET DRAWING PER APPLICABLE STANDARD: Accenture  ACCOO1 "; "yoyoyo heloo"
These are the logical groups of text.  I never said property of accenture will be in different group.

Comment: In your desired output that you have shown in the question, can you give an example for the condition `left`,

Comment: Also when i use this solution it is not giving me the desired output which you have printed. From the new page it is again starting the group number from 1. 
@Jeril

Comment: I have updated the solution for group number continuation, can you check

Comment: Still not the output you printed, it is continuing group 3 where it should be 4. @Jeril

Comment: can you share the .tsv

Comment: how to share .tsv file directly to you ? Can you send me email id ?

Comment: Okay mate if have sent you the mail do check it ! @Jeril

Comment: Can you confirm that you received the mail ?@Jeril