# Save excel file using python

Tags: python, pandas, save

I have a problem. I perform data cleaning on excel file using python in Jupiter notebook. There are 10 sheets in my excel file. My cleaning is done successfully. But when I open excel it same as before cleaning. How can I save my data permanently in an excel file using python pandas?
I import file using ***import os***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dataframe to Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459461/dataframe-to-excel-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to save your clean data and then you can directly open that file

df.to_csv(location,index=False)

Comment: But my excel file is of .xlsx type and whenever I tried df.to_excel(location, index=False), it does not save changes that I performed through data cleaning. Any solution?

Comment: df.to_excel("output.xlsx",index=False)