# I want to convert the following text file into one having the headers as columns and the corresponding data in rows

Tags: python, json, excel, data-analysis

All the data I have are in text files (.txt) right after download. I have multiples files like these (atleast 70000) which I was thinking I'll merge first into a single mastertext file using the copy.txt in cmd. Then I'd want to analyse the mastertext file by so an ideal output would be .csv file.

The data needs to be converted into a table like structure for analysis purposes. Every file (out of the 70000 .txt files I have) starts with a '['and ends with ']' and every new row of data starts with '{' and ends with '}', I have multiple rows of data with the same format. I would like the converted data to have headers such as 'campaignId' so that I can analyze columns using pivots (like how you'd do in excel). I'm a novice at programming and am not sure which libraries in Python can help me accomplish my goal.

Here is an example of the data I have. (Note - These are just two rows in one file and I have around 70000 files like these)

```
{
    "campaignId": "all",
    "startDate": "2020-06-11",
    "endDate": "2020-06-11",
    "device": "Computers",
    "network": "Display Network",
    "channel": "all",
    "accLevelQS": -1.0,
    "impressions": 389,
    "clicks": 3,
    "ctr": 0.0,
    "avgCPC": 0.0,
    "convValuePerClick": 0.0,
    "convValuePerCost": 0.0,
    "costConv1PerClick": 0.0,
    "convRate1PerClick": 0.0,
    "cost": 0.142884,
    "conv1PerClick": 0.0,
    "totalConvValue": 0.00,
    "allConversions": 0.0,
    "allConversionValue": 0.00,
    "avgPosition": 0.0,
    "intr": 3,
    "searchImprShare": 0.0,
    "contImprShare": 5.0,
    "impressionShare": 5.0
},
{
    "campaignId": "all",
    "startDate": "2020-06-11",
    "endDate": "2020-06-11",
    "device": "Mobile devices with full browsers",
    "network": "Display Network",
    "channel": "all",
    "accLevelQS": -1.0,
    "impressions": 6101,
    "clicks": 90,
    "ctr": 0.0,
    "avgCPC": 0.0,
    "convValuePerClick": 0.0,
    "convValuePerCost": 0.0,
    "costConv1PerClick": 0.0,
    "convRate1PerClick": 0.0,
    "cost": 4.342799,
    "conv1PerClick": 0.0,
    "totalConvValue": 0.00,
    "allConversions": 0.0,
    "allConversionValue": 0.00,
    "avgPosition": 0.0,
    "intr": 90,
    "searchImprShare": 0.0,
    "contImprShare": 5.0077566465021217,
    "impressionShare": 5.0077566465021217
}
```

Comment: Use pandas library

Comment: Welcome. Can you tell us more about the input format and the desired output format? Eg, is the incoming data JSON and you want it in a CSV file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dataframe to Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459461/dataframe-to-excel-sheet)

Comment: So all the data I have are text files (.txt) right after download. I have multiples files like these (atleast 70000) which I was thinking I'll merge first into a single mastertext file using the copy.txt in cmd. Then I'd want the mastertext file so an ideal output would be .csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have made some assumptions as the data you have provided seems like a list of JSON data. This is because there is a "," in between your entries.

Here is my `input.json` file. Notice I have added [ and ] at the top and bottom, as this would give your data a proper JSON structure.

```
[
  {
    "campaignId": "all",
    "startDate": "2020-06-11",
    "endDate": "2020-06-11",
    "device": "Computers",
    "network": "Display Network",
    "channel": "all",
    "accLevelQS": -1.0,
    "impressions": 389,
    "clicks": 3,
    "ctr": 0.0,
    "avgCPC": 0.0,
    "convValuePerClick": 0.0,
    "convValuePerCost": 0.0,
    "costConv1PerClick": 0.0,
    "convRate1PerClick": 0.0,
    "cost": 0.142884,
    "conv1PerClick": 0.0,
    "totalConvValue": 0.00,
    "allConversions": 0.0,
    "allConversionValue": 0.00,
    "avgPosition": 0.0,
    "intr": 3,
    "searchImprShare": 0.0,
    "contImprShare": 5.0,
    "impressionShare": 5.0
  },
  {
    "campaignId": "all",
    "startDate": "2020-06-11",
    "endDate": "2020-06-11",
    "device": "Mobile devices with full browsers",
    "network": "Display Network",
    "channel": "all",
    "accLevelQS": -1.0,
    "impressions": 6101,
    "clicks": 90,
    "ctr": 0.0,
    "avgCPC": 0.0,
    "convValuePerClick": 0.0,
    "convValuePerCost": 0.0,
    "costConv1PerClick": 0.0,
    "convRate1PerClick": 0.0,
    "cost": 4.342799,
    "conv1PerClick": 0.0,
    "totalConvValue": 0.00,
    "allConversions": 0.0,
    "allConversionValue": 0.00,
    "avgPosition": 0.0,
    "intr": 90,
    "searchImprShare": 0.0,
    "contImprShare": 5.0077566465021217,
    "impressionShare": 5.0077566465021217
  }
]
```

Here is the code which uses the `pandas` library to process the data into a dataframe and then write it to a CSV file.

```
import json  # Available by default, no install required.
import glob  # Available by default, no install required.
import pandas as pd  # Requires installation via pip.

# Initialise a list to store our results.
combined_json = []

# Set a glob pattern to *.txt since your files are txt files.
# You can also write the full path e.g. /home/user/textfiles/*.txt
text_files = glob.glob("*.txt")

# Loop through all the text files and combine them into a single JSON list.
# As for 70,000 files, I am unsure how the performance will turn out.
for json_text in text_files:
    with open(json_text, 'r') as text_file:
        combined_json.extend(json.load(text_file))

# Write all the files to a JSON file. For your future usage.
# You also can read directly from the combed_json variable.
with open('input.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(combined_json, json_file, indent=2)

# Convert the JSON data into a dataframe, using the combined_json variable.
json_df = pd.json_normalize(combined_json)

# Write the data from the dataframe to the CSV file.
# Mode "w" will always overwrite the CSV file, use mode "a" to append text instead of overwriting.
json_df.to_csv("dataframe.csv", mode="w")
```

For more information on how `pd.json_normalize` works, you can refer [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html).

To get started with the `pandas` library, you can refer [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html).

If you wish to load the JSON from a string instead of a file, you can refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp).

To learn more about `glob`, you can refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_glob.asp).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for taking the time out to show this. So all the files that I've received after download are .txt files (I've copied the data above directly from there by opening it in notepad). Now I have another issue. I have around 70k such text files which I was planning to merge into a single mastertext file so that I can use that for analysis. As you mentioned, all data in the files start with "["and end with "]" and when merging these square brackets are copied for every file (so there are multiple square brackets). Would that be an issue when implementing what you've told?

Comment: Before coming to that, since these files are text files would json commands using pandas work on them in the first place?

Comment: So you should have specified this in your initial question. Firstly you can combine all the text files into one large .json files by separating each entry with a comma and then wrapping them with square brackets. You can follow my example above.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry, my bad! Should've specified everything clearly. 

I'm planning to combine all the 70000 .txt files into a single .txt file using the cmd in windows. Then I'll just open the master .txt file using notepad and use the replace all function to remove all the extra square brackets so that there's only one at the beginning and the end (for proper json format). Then probably doing what you've told should do the job hopefully!

Comment: No worries, I make mistakes too. Yes, you should have just one square bracket at the top and one at the bottom. Make sure after each entry there is a comma, except for the last entry. Like mentioned, you can refer to my example. You also mentioned that your text files have square brackets? If so, this means they are in JSON format already. @Rakshit

Comment: I'm completely new to programming and hence still trying to get my head around things. I've added more details to my question which you should be able to view now hopefully. 

Yes, all the text files do have the square brackets at the beginning and the end (so they are in JSON format but are saved as .txt files). I was wondering whether it'd be possible to merge all the .txt files directly using python since they're already in JSON format and then do what you told? If that's not feasible, then as I'd mentioned I'd first just combine all the .txt files into one using cmd and then proceed.

Comment: @Rakshit I have edited my answer.  It should merge all your text files into one large JSON file and then convert it into a CSV file. As far as performance goes, I am unsure how fast or slow it will be. It depends on how big each of your text files are.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try this out and let you know :)

Comment: Hey! Yes, it did! Thanks a lot! Got lost in analysing these large amounts of data and hence forgot to respond here

Answer (score 0):

Each of your text enclose within the `{}` is actually of type `dict`. This type can be easily converted to pandas using the  `pd.DataFrame` and finally converted to excel using the `to_excel`.

The full code then can be written as below:

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict_1={
  "campaignId": "all", "startDate":"2020-06-11", "endDate":"2020-06-11", "device":"Computers", "network":"Display Network", "channel":"all", "accLevelQS":-1.0, "impressions":389, "clicks":3, "ctr":0.0, "avgCPC":0.0, "convValuePerClick":0.0, "convValuePerCost":0.0, "costConv1PerClick":0.0, "convRate1PerClick":0.0, "cost":0.142884, "conv1PerClick":0.0, "totalConvValue":0.00, "allConversions":0.0, "allConversionValue":0.00, "avgPosition":0.0, "intr":3, "searchImprShare":0.0, "contImprShare":5.0, "impressionShare":5.0
}
my_dict_2={
  "campaignId": "all", "startDate":"2020-06-11", "endDate":"2020-06-11", "device":"Mobile devices with full browsers", "network":"Display Network", "channel":"all", "accLevelQS":-1.0, "impressions":6101, "clicks":90, "ctr":0.0, "avgCPC":0.0, "convValuePerClick":0.0, "convValuePerCost":0.0, "costConv1PerClick":0.0, "convRate1PerClick":0.0, "cost":4.342799, "conv1PerClick":0.0, "totalConvValue":0.00, "allConversions":0.0, "allConversionValue":0.00, "avgPosition":0.0, "intr":90, "searchImprShare":0.0, "contImprShare":5.0077566465021217, "impressionShare":5.0077566465021217
}
all_dict=[my_dict_1,my_dict_2]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(all_dict)
df1.to_excel("output.xlsx",index = False)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'd not mentioned all the required details in my question earlier and have modified it now. You can have look at the same and perhaps modify your answer accordingly. Thanks and sorry!