# How can I write to B column of an existing excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I am completely new to programming and I have a problem like every beginner I guess:). So basically I am trying to convert/calculate some numbers using this formula: (((prices*1.1)/8.6)+1+3.75+1)/0.76 and I could convert every number (there are like 1000) with this code

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\\Users\\bbura\\Downloads\\test1.xlsx")
list = data["TL Price"].tolist()
for prices in list:
  result = (((prices*1.1)/8.6)+1+3.75+1)/0.76
  print(result)
```

I need to write these new prices into column B of test1.xlsx file and I have no idea how to do that.

Thanks for your help and please forgive my bad english.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dataframe to Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459461/dataframe-to-excel-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Alignment to your code you can do :

```
data = pd.read_excel(r"C:\\Users\\bbura\\Downloads\\test1.xlsx")
list_ = data["TL Price"].tolist()
B_col = []
for prices in list:
   result = (((prices*1.1)/8.6)+1+3.75+1)/0.76
   B_col.append(result)

data['B'] = B_col
```

But this involves lot of lines. One liner by @Myrt is more useful.
Also, you are using list as variable name, which is conflicting as
list is predefined keyword in python.

Answer (score -1):

you may want to use the apply function

```
data['B']=data['TL Price'].apply(lambda x: (((x*1.1)/8.6)+1+3.75+1)/0.76)
```